# 18.04: Installing packages using android command line tools

Tags: software-installation, android, android-sdk

I'm trying to use the Android SDK in Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS without installing Android Studio because of hardware constraints.

So I've been following this tutorial https://dev.to/jay_js/setting-up-flutter-without-android-studio-olo so far so good, up until 
`sdkmanager "system-images;android-29;google_apis;x86_64"`

When i try executing that code i get `Warning: Failed to read or create install properties file.` I went into my 'Android' directory and saw these files only:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/pY7KR.png ] (screenshot from my pc).

Further into tools directory:[https://i.stack.imgur.com/bD22G.png ]

Am i missing files or what?

**NB i plan on using the sdk for visual studio code. Feel free to ask for more screenshots:)**

**SYSTEM INFO** [https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIsS4.png ]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer:) Just execute the command below:

```
sudo chmod -R a+w [path/to/android/sdk]
```

Source:[https://github.com/bitrise-steplib/steps-install-missing-android-tools/issues/57 ]

Comment: Thank you so much, I spent hours trying to figure it out and this worked!

Comment: Thanks for the help :)